# QuickFIX/J rotate .messages.log

Tags: log4j, slf4j, quickfixj

Except for [that post](http://quickfix-developers.narkive.com/IGK98dNZ/message-logs-rotation-and-persistmessages), I can't find anything on the web that is a good answer to that question.

Is there any way to rotate log files with QuickFIX/J ? I am using Log4j to rotate my log files, but I was not able to rotate the QuickFIX messages.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem and can't find a good way to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
cd <fix log directory>
for i in *; do echo -n | sudo tee $i; done
```

This truncated the logs 0 bytes. Fix operation continues fine and the logs are being filled from the start again. So, truncation (and rotation w/ truncatio) is supported. (quickfix/j 1.6.1)